# How to handle when an item is not selected in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner in my application but selecting a value is not mandatory to go to next activity. When I select an item and pressed the button it goes to the next activity without any problem. But press the button without selecting any value then it gives me an exception.

In that case what should I do when any item is not selected.

```
addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            String instructions = instructionsET.getText().toString();
            String Strquantity = quantityET.getText().toString();
            String description = descriptionTV.getText().toString();
            String extraCheese = extraCheseChTV.getText().toString();
            String crust = crustSP.getSelectedItem().toString(); //go to exception from here

            if (Utility.isNotNull(Strquantity) && Utility.isNotNull(crust)) {
                if (Utility.validateItemQuantity(Strquantity)) {
                    if (instructionsET.getText().toString()
                                    .equals(instructions)
                                    && quantityET.getText().toString()
                                    .equals(Strquantity)) {

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Items processing to the cart...",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
               }
        }
}
```

[image]

adapter

```
package lk.gamma.pizzakraft.customize;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;

/**
 * Decorator Adapter to allow a Spinner to show a 'Nothing Selected...' initially
 * displayed instead of the first choice in the Adapter.
 */
public class NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter, ListAdapter {

    protected static final int EXTRA = 1;
    protected SpinnerAdapter adapter;
    protected Context context;
    protected int nothingSelectedLayout;
    protected int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
    protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    /**
     * Use this constructor to have NO 'Select One...' item, instead use
     * the standard prompt or nothing at all.
     * @param spinnerAdapter wrapped Adapter.
     * @param nothingSelectedLayout layout for nothing selected, perhaps
     * you want text grayed out like a prompt...
     * @param context
     */
    public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
      SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
      int nothingSelectedLayout, Context context) {

        this(spinnerAdapter, nothingSelectedLayout, -1, context);
    }

    /**
     * Use this constructor to Define your 'Select One...' layout as the first
     * row in the returned choices.
     * If you do this, you probably don't want a prompt on your spinner or it'll
     * have two 'Select' rows.
     * @param spinnerAdapter wrapped Adapter. Should probably return false for isEnabled(0)
     * @param nothingSelectedLayout layout for nothing selected, perhaps you want
     * text grayed out like a prompt...
     * @param nothingSelectedDropdownLayout layout for your 'Select an Item...' in
     * the dropdown.
     * @param context
     */
    public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
            int nothingSelectedLayout, int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, Context context) {
        this.adapter = spinnerAdapter;
        this.context = context;
        this.nothingSelectedLayout = nothingSelectedLayout;
        this.nothingSelectedDropdownLayout = nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public final View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // This provides the View for the Selected Item in the Spinner, not
        // the dropdown (unless dropdownView is not set).
        if (position == 0) {
            return getNothingSelectedView(parent);
        }
        return adapter.getView(position - EXTRA, null, parent); // Could re-use
                                                 // the convertView if possible.
    }

    /**
     * View to show in Spinner with Nothing Selected
     * Override this to do something dynamic... e.g. "37 Options Found"
     * @param parent
     * @return
     */
    protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Android BUG! http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17128 -
        // Spinner does not support multiple view types
        if (position == 0) {
            return nothingSelectedDropdownLayout == -1 ?
              new View(context) :
              getNothingSelectedDropdownView(parent);
        }

        // Could re-use the convertView if possible, use setTag...
        return adapter.getDropDownView(position - EXTRA, null, parent);
    }

    /**
     * Override this to do something dynamic... For example, "Pick your favorite
     * of these 37".
     * @param parent
     * @return
     */
    protected View getNothingSelectedDropdownView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int count = adapter.getCount();
        return count == 0 ? 0 : count + EXTRA;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? null : adapter.getItem(position - EXTRA);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position >= EXTRA ? adapter.getItemId(position - EXTRA) : position - EXTRA;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return adapter.hasStableIds();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return adapter.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return position == 0 ? false : true; // Don't allow the 'nothing selected'
                                             // item to be picked.
    }

}
```

Comment: are you populating your spinner with a custom adapter ?

Comment: yh im using an adapter to show select item entity at the top. wait ill upload that code

Comment: If selecting a value from the spinner is optional, just make sure you do a null check on it before attempting to call `toString()`? You'll also want to change the business logic that follows: `Utility.isNotNull(crust)` will most likely return `false` when no value is selected.

Comment: your spinner is optional but you are assuming that user has selected some value and then you are trying to retrieve it and converting it to string but if the user is not selected any value then it provides null and throws the nullpointerexception

Comment: @MH. it doesn't go to Utility.isNotNull(crust), it's value is null thats the thing. Can u tell me what should I do to over come.

Comment: @Pramod Yadav yh its value is null. Can u tell me what should I do to over come that issue.

Comment: @JohnDavid: As I said earlier, it could be as simple as doing a null check first -> `String crust = crustSP.getSelectedItem() != null ? crustSP.getSelectedItem().toString() : null;`. That should prevent the exception from being thrown, but you may have to change the logic that follows to take into account the scenario where `crust == null`.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting your selected value via this code:-

```
String crust = crustSP.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

but is the value is not selected is provides null,so change it to

```
String crust = crustSP.getSelectedItem();
```

check that crust is not null and if it is not null then convert it to string

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got better answer from  MH. so I can't vote you. sorry about that.